# How to style the end of a line?

Tags: qgis, style, line

In the picture you can see, the red lines i added manually. These are the ends of the lines. To distinguish that there is the beginning of a new river segment, i would like to have something like these read breaks at the end or between each line segments automatically.
Is there any posibility to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add another layer into your style as "marker line" and draw markers only at line ends. See the screen capture below.
[image: Adding a marker layer in QGIS 2.0.1]

Comment: Could you tell me which version of ArcGIS this is?  I am working in ArcGIS 10.2.1 and cannot find the options presented in your screen capture.

Comment: It is QGIS not ArcGIS.